# Children of Lazy Loaded Modules routes don't work

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-router

I can't get the routing of a lazy loaded module working. Please have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bah9hf?file=src/app/orders/orders-routing.module.ts), it's a copy from the [Angular lazy loading example](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) with a few changes.

- First of all, the lazy loading itself seems to be working correctly
- If I click the "orders" button the module is (lazy) loaded and the correct component is being displayed (`OrdersComponent`)
- However, clicking "Orders Child" also displays the orders component (instead of the `OrdersComponent2`)
- When I un-comment the `pathMatch: 'full'` in the child route configuration I'll get an error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'orders/child'` for the child route

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not use `pathMath: full` when you have child-cmps.

There are two possibilities

1. add a router-outlet to your orders component if your orders2 should be nested within the orders component.

```html
<p>
  orders works!
</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

2. move the orders component to children:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: OrdersComponent
      },
      {
        path: "child",
        component: OrdersComponent2
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

EDIT:

or remove children and setup like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: OrdersComponent
  },
  {
    path: "child",
    component: OrdersComponent2
  }
];
```

let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

You defined `OrdersComponent2` as a child route to `OrdersComponent`: this has nothing to do with lazy loaded modules. They belong to the same module, that is lazy loaded once you navigate to `/orders`.

What you're doing by clicking the "Order Child" button is navigating to the child route `/orders/child`: for that to work you need a `<router-outlet>` in the `orders.component.html template`. That outlet will be used by Angular to display the child view.

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bah9hf-xqjg4f)

Answer (score -1):

In your orders-routing-module.ts, the problem is where you specify the path:

```
path: "child",
```

There are no components with the selector "app-child", so it will give you the "cannot match any routes" error. Your orders.component.ts has the child component with selector
"app-orders-2", so try this path and the error should disappear and the content show:

```
path: "orders-2",
```

Comment: Just to give you some feedback: the path has nothing to do with the component-selector.
the path is the url in the browser with the property component you define what component gets called. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: That makes sense, however for best practice, the path should where possible correspond to a component selector. I agree that the child "child" component should be a component within the Order subfolder which has it's own routing module.