# How can I route my angular child pages without error?

Tags: angular

I cannot route my angular child pages.
Please help me to solve this. I have attached my routing module down BELOW FOR more details.

its submodule of app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
     import { BillingSetupComponent } from './Setup/billing-setup/billing-setup.component';
     import { NewBillingMasterComponent } from './Master Billing/new-billing-master/new-billing- 
              master.component';
  import { NewBillingSubMasterComponent } from './Master Billing/new-billing-sub-master/new-billing- 
   sub-master.component';



      export const routes: Routes = [
         {
         path: '', component: BillingSetupComponent,

      children: [

    { path: 'Setup', component: BillingSetupComponent },
    { path: 'Master', component: NewBillingMasterComponent },
    { path: 'SubMaster', component: NewBillingSubMasterComponent },
  
           ]
         }
          ]


         @NgModule({
            imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
          exports: [RouterModule]
             })



             export class ConfigurationRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config only work when there a router-outlet in BillingSetupComponent. We cannot help you to find the problem with your code posted. Please provide more code or you can check example for child route here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: Yep it only can route child-routes if there is a router-outlet in the parent
Also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367245/children-of-lazy-loaded-modules-routes-dont-work/

Answer (score 0):

try to delete export from this line export const routes: Routes and add path before children like my example that worked for me

[image: my router example]